# Using undocumented native code APIs to install items into the GAC

Tags: api, installation, gac

I'm working on a project whose setup uses the APIs documented in Microsoft Knowledge Base article [KB317540](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317540) to install and uninstall assemblies into the GAC. The KB article states:

> SUMMARY
>   The native code application
>   programming interfaces (APIs) that
>   allow you to interact with the Global
>   Assembly Cache (GAC) are not
>   documented  in the .NET Framework
>   Software Development Kit (SDK)
>   documentation.
>
> MORE INFORMATION
>   CAUTION: Do not use
>   these APIs in your application to
>   perform assembly binds or to test for
>   the presence of assemblies or other
>   run time,  development, or design-time
>   operations. Only administrative tools
>   and setup programs must use these
>   APIs. If you use the GAC, this
>   directly  exposes your application to
>   assembly binding fragility or may
>   cause your application to work
>   improperly on future versions of the
>   .NET  Framework.
>
> The GAC stores assemblies that are
>   shared across all applications on a
>   computer. The actual storage location
>   and structure of the GAC is  not
>   documented and is subject to change in
>   future versions of the .NET Framework
>   and the Microsoft Windows operating
>   system.
>
> The only supported method to access
>   assemblies in the GAC is through the
>   APIs that are documented in this
>   article.
>
> Most applications do not have to use
>   these APIs because the assembly
>   binding is performed automatically by
>   the common language runtime.  Only
>   custom setup programs or management
>   tools must use these APIs. Microsoft
>   Windows Installer has native support
>   for installing assemblies  to the GAC.
>
> For more information about assemblies
>   and the GAC, see the .NET Framework
>   SDK.
>
> Use the GAC API in the following
>   scenarios:  When you install an
>   assembly to the GAC. When you remove
>   an assembly from the GAC. When you
>   export an assembly from the GAC. When
>   you enumerate assemblies that are
>   available in the GAC. NOTE:
>   CoInitialize(Ex) must be called before
>   you use any of the functions and
>   interfaces that are described in this
>   specification.

What are the pros and cons of this technique? Are these APIs safe to use? Anyone out there using them? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a Windows Installer package? See [Demystifying the .NET Global Assembly Cache](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/demystifygac.aspx). Quoting:

> Developers of Windows Installer
>   packages can install assemblies to the
>   GAC using Microsoft Windows Installer
>   2.0. This is the preferred way for installing such shared assemblies and
>   should be the only way shared
>   assemblies are installed on non
>   development machines.

Comment: If it were up to me, that's exactly what I would do, but the others in my team seem to think that Windows Installer is "too difficult" and they want to use Inno Setup. This really smells bad to me, but I'm currently outnumbered :(

Comment: @Tim: I found this link that may help: https://msmvps.com/blogs/carlosq/archive/2009/06/09/net-support-in-next-version-of-innosetup-installer-handy-for-com-based-add-ins.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It says, "Only administrative tools and setup programs must use these APIs."

There are tools (e.g. command-line tools) to work with the GAC. Why not invoke these executables, instead of using these APIs directly?

Comment: Right, yes, I know what it says - the problem there is that my team members think they are "creating a setup program". I think they've misinterpreted the statement. To me, that means that your process name has to be MSIExec if you want to use these APIs. However, Inno Setup (the tool being used) spits out a setup.exe that "sets up the product" - it is a "setup program". I'm sure you can see the ambiguity there.

Comment: I think it might be much easier (e.g. 1 line of code) to invoke the command-line tool, instead of using an API like that one.